# Set DPI of Logitech MX Master (2S) over Bluetooth in Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech MX Master and a Logitech MX Master 2S. Until recently I used a Unifying receiver to connect with the mouse. The sensitivity was a bit too low with both both mouses, but acceptable.

I stopped using the Unifying receiver because of the recently published security vulnerabilities. Instead I connect them with Bluetooth.

The sensitivity of the MX Master is the same as over the Unifying receiver, but the sensitivity of the MX Master 2S is lower than over the Unifying receiver.

The sensor is capable of a higher DPI. How can I increase the sensitivity?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration

Comment: @xenoid It seems like this will increase the speed, but not the DPI of the sensor, therefore decreasing precision.

Comment: Same issue here. This is incredibly annoying.

Comment: [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) is now said to fully support the MX Master 2S and have a better GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out finally:

```
xinput set-prop "MX Master 2S Mouse" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

Adjusting the two diagonal values (those set to 4.000000 above) will tweak the sensitivity. Setting it to 4.000000 feels roughly the same as the unifying receiver default.

(Not sure why it needs so many decimal places but I was getting errors if I didn't specify the trailing zeros)

Comment: Note that this isn't increasing the sensitivity, it just multiplies the received values by 4, so the pointer moves four times as fast with the same sensitivity. Which of course is fine if you weren't after increasing the sensitivity, but wanted a movement speed that feels good for you.

Comment: Yes that's technically true, although it's not clear to me:
1) What the default DPI of the mouse is
2) Whether it is even possible to adjust it via bluetooth

Comment: It's not clear to me, either. Bluetooth is a bit of a mess on Linux, so my guess is that *if* it's possible to adjust it, you'd have to mess around directly with Bluetooth via the DBUS interface. But that's a conjecture. As I don't have this hardware, I can't find out.

Answer (score 1):

The libratbag/[piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/wiki/Installation) project appears to have support for configuring the MX Master 2S on linux. It has settings for polling rate 500/1000 Hz and also DPI.

[image: Piper MX Master 2S]

<s>However, trying to change this on the current version (0.3-201910041847) pops up with an error</s>

> Something went wrong. The device has been reset to the previous state.

This is trying it over the Bluetooth connection; I haven't tried with the dongle/unified receiver as I've lost it.

Hopefully this will be fixed soon! I think that would solve your problem.

Comment: Between asking the question and your answer, I successfully changed the DPI using "ratbagctl warbling-mara dpi set 4000". However, shortly afterwards, after upgrading my system, it stopped working for an unknown reason. Trying it with Piper, I get the same error as you. I’m sorry if you spent extra effort because I didn’t report the intermediate status here.